# How to remove "no data" labels from empty nodes in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.4, gwt-widgets

I have a widget that inherits from `CellTree`. If the node not have the child elements, this node can be opened and shows `"no data"` label.

I'd like to see nodes without child's displayed as empty.

That's how I fill the tree. My `DictionaryTreeDataProvider` class (relevant part):

```
public class DictionaryTreeDataProvider extends ListDataProvider<MValue> {
    private final DictionariesServiceAsync service = GWT.create(DictionariesService.class);

    ...    

    @Override
    public void onRangeChanged(HasData<MValue> result) {
        service.queryDictionaryValues(range, query, new AsyncCallback<SubsetResult<MValue>>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SubsetResult<MValue> result) {
                getList().clear();
                for (MValue value : result.items) {
                    getList().add(value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On the server side I make EJB call which fills `SubsetResult`.
I found that this problem fixed in version of GWT-2.5.0-rc2 (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/d-rFUmyHTT4).

---

Now everything is OK, thanks to @moutellou. 
I did as he suggested:

```
...
@Override
public void onSuccess(SubsetResult<MValue> result) {
    if (result.length == 0) {
        updateRowCount(-1, true);
        return;
    } else {
        for (MValue value : result.items) {
            // some checks here
            getList().add(value);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: How do you fetch the data. Are you using AsyncDataProvider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I removed the no data label in my DataProvider

```
 //Fetch children
  int size = children.size();
  if (size == 0) {
     updateRowCount(-1, true); //Method called on AsyncDataProvider 
     return;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative solution. Can be defined interface that extends the interface `CellTree.Resources`. 
In this interface must specify the path to the CSS, which override the desired style.

Interface `CellTree.Resources`:

```
public class CellTree extends AbstractCellTree implements HasAnimation,
    Focusable {
   ...  
  /**
   * A ClientBundle that provides images for this widget.
   */
  public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    /**
     * An image indicating a closed branch.
     */
    @ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
    @Source("cellTreeClosedArrow.png")
    ImageResource cellTreeClosedItem();

    /**
     * An image indicating that a node is loading.
     */
    @ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
    ImageResource cellTreeLoading();

    /**
     * An image indicating an open branch.
     */
    @ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
    @Source("cellTreeOpenArrow.png")
    ImageResource cellTreeOpenItem();

    /**
     * The background used for selected items.
     */
    @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Horizontal, flipRtl = true)
    ImageResource cellTreeSelectedBackground();

    /**
     * The styles used in this widget.
     */
    @Source(Style.DEFAULT_CSS)
    Style cellTreeStyle();
  } 
...
}
```

Interface `CustomCellTreeResources`, based on `CellTree.Resources`:

```
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTree;

public interface CustomCellTreeResources extends CellTree.Resources {
    static final String STYLE_PATH = "components/common/client/static/custom-cell-tree.css";

    @Override
    @ClientBundle.Source({CellTree.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, STYLE_PATH})
    CellTree.Style cellTreeStyle();
}
```

Overriding rule:

```
.cellTreeEmptyMessage {
    display: none;
}
```

Create an instance:

```
private final static CellTree.Resources customCellTreeResources = 
    GWT.create(CustomCellTreeResources.class);
```

And next need to explicitly pass `customCellTreeResources` to the `CellTree` class constructor.

Message is not displayed more.

Mandatory: before filing the list, ie, before clicking on a node, the list should be cleaned(                `getList().clear();`):

```
@Override
public void onRangeChanged(HasData<MValue> result) {
    service.queryDictionaryValues(range, query, 
          new AsyncCallback<SubsetResult<MValue>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {}
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SubsetResult<MValue> result) {
            getList().clear();
            for (MValue value : result.items) {
                getList().add(value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `TreeViewModel`, make sure that the `isLeaf` method returns `true` if the argument value has no children. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof DepartmentDto) {
        DepartmentDto department = (DepartmentDto) value;
        return department.getEmployees().isEmpty();
    } else if (value instanceof EmployeeDto) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case, a department should declare itself as a leaf only if it has no employees, an employee will declare itself as a leaf, and default to false.

Note that value many also be an internal GWT node. In this example, it might not necessarily be just `DepartmentDto` and `EmployeeDto`.